# How to match texts in Excel

Tags: excel, vlookup

Here is my data:
in Column A, the sheet 1 I have this data

```html
Name
Ali,hok
Bab,mko
Katie,Mon
NA
NA
NA
NA
john,Nulla
NA
NA
```

In Sheet 2, I have this data

```html
Name    Class
Katie,Mon   AS1
Ali,hok MNO1
john,Nulla  KAL1
Katie,Mon   Nook
Bab,mko BAR11
```

I want to get this data in sheet 1

```html
Name    Class
Ali,hok MNO1
Bab,mko BAR11
Katie,Mon   AS1
NA  NA
NA  NA
NA  NA
NA  NA
john,Nulla  KAL1
NA  NA
NA  NA
```

I have followed the Vlookup function, but I did not get the outcome of interest. Can we do it with other functions, or what is wrong with excel

Comment: please next time try to work more on the question, so it is easier to reproduce the sample and help you.

Comment: Which version of excel do you use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple `VLOOKUP()` should work in your case. You may have spaces or comma differences. Have a try on wild card matching with first name (before comma) with `Sheet2` data. Use `INDEX()/MATCH()` combination with wild card. To suppress error use `IFERROR()`. Try below formula-

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet2!$B$2:$B$6,MATCH("*" & LEFT(A2,SEARCH(",",A2)-1) & "*",Sheet2!$A$2:$A$6,0)),"")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understood your question well and the lookup table has a repeated entry: `Katie, Mon`, so the lookup function will get the last match. Here is the solution:
[image: Sheet1]

where Sheet 2 is:

[image: Sheet2]

Note you can remove `#N/A` replacing the formula by:`IFNA(VLOOKUP(A2,Sheet2!$A$2:$B$6, 2, FALSE),"")`

Comment: Thanks, I have tried it already but I get #N/A for all